# how to add image from sd card in email body nt as an attachment?

Tags: android

in my app i want upload image from android in built gallery and this uploaded image want to use in next view . in next view i want the show that image and use it in email body part.
the problem is the uploaded image shown in both activity but not displayed in email body.
plz can any one help me to solve this query.....

Comment: Did you got any solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the images to the email body. Email body can contain html or plain text. You can only attach the image to email.

Comment: hi i got the attachment code.....but client want image in email body only....and not as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image you want to embed into HTML tags, try to render the HTML on to the composer body. As Composer is also an HTML composer this trial should work